# How to refresh a VF page from lightning component included in subtab

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have added a lightning component in a subtab(Actions) of Account detail in Lightning experience. There is one other subtab(Account Plan) which is showing a VF page.

Now I want to refresh the VF page from the lightning component without reloading the URL.

[image]

Comment: You may try Platform Events: 1. You need to publish the event at a place where you are performing record creation.(ie. in Apex Class). 2. And you need to subscribe the event in your VF page like the example mentioned here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196241/subscribe-to-platform-event-in-visualforce

Answer (score 0):

Try using lightning events.

If you trigger an application event on your Actions lightning component, then you need to listen to that event on your other component for refreshing it.

Now - because your other component is a VF page and not a real component, you are in a problem.

So if you can migrate that VF page into a component, you can implement an event listener over there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this issue try to convert your VF to Lightning component.
Then in your Lightning controller add this code.
Refresh view:

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

Hope this will help you.